# Using the STL stack as a member of a C++ class

Tags: c++, class, stl, stack

I am working on a project that requires a list(singly) of stacks. I have made a class called "stacklist" that is just that, a list of stacks. I want the class to have a stack pointer that will point to the head of the list. However, I keep getting an error whenever I try to build the class.

```
#ifndef STACKLIST_H
#define STACKLIST_H

#include <stack>

//source: Data Structures Using C++: Linked List Implementation Part II (List Class)
//url: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=endscreen&NR=1&v=7vZo17iv1zQ
class stacklist
{
    public:
        stacklist();
        void addToHead(const int&);
        void printList();
        void insert(const int&);

    private:
        stack<int>* head; //THIS IS WHERE I AM HAVING THE PROBLEM
        int size;

};



#endif // STACKLIST_H
```

The error message is "error: expected ';' before '<' token"

Any insight that can be provided would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Just use `std::stack` instead of just `stack` and everything should be fine.

Answer (score 6):

The standard library `stack` lives in the `std` namespace, so you need to qualify the name appropriately:

```
std::stack<int>* head;
```

You should consider using an `std::list<std::stack<int>>` instead of your class.

Answer (score 5):

The correct name of the template is `std::stack`.

If all you want is a list of stacks, you could always use `std::list<std::stack<int>>`, by the way (or `std::forward_list` if you only need forward traversal). But even if you pursued your own design, there's probably no reason why you can't make the stack a direct class member.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should say `std::stack`

`std::stack<int>* head;` instead `stack<int>* head;`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `std` libraries, you must put `std::` before the std object or place a `using namespace std` at the beggining of your source file:

```
#include <stack>
using namespace std; // This line brings std stuff into the current namespace.
```

Or:

```
std::stack<int>* head;
```

If your file is a header, it's better the first one than the second one because the `using` directive will be spreaded into all the files that includes `StackList.h`

This is no mentioned on the question, but I think is worth to say: Is quite dangerous to use pointers into classes, because you must take care of it into all constructors (default and copy) and take care on destructor too.

Revise your class dessign and think if you can use a `std::stack` instance instead of `std::stack` pointer.